# Why can't I login to chat.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, chat, login

I've logged into chat.stackexchange.com several before and been able to chat, so I'm sure my account is signed up there, however I can't login there now.  Whenever I go to:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackexchange.com%2f

... I always get the error 'Your login data seems too old; please log in to any StackExchange site to refresh it.'  I've tried logging out and logging in again in other StackExchange sites, closing/opening the browser (Firefox 3), and even using another browser with a fresh profile (Opera 11), but I continue to get the same problem logging into chat.

UPDATE: Looks like the problem only happens with the subdomain chat.stackexchange.com.  So, I visit:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95

... for example, and although I can see the chat, it seems to think I'm not logged in and says I must log in to be able to chat.  I can't login because of the above problem.  However, I can chat no problem on, say:

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89

Comment: I have the same problem; http://chat.stackexchange.com/help reports all is OK, but logging in to chat.stackexchange.com still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you try Jeff's link above, and everything reports OK but it still doesn't work, please let me know. In the interim, there is a ghetto login route:

```
http://{some site}/users/chat-stackexchange-login
```

for example:     https://stackoverflow.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login

Comment: It did indeed all report OK and still not work (from this, my work PC)... though I was able to login from my home PC, weirdly.  That 'ghetto login' works too, and once I'm logged in via that on a Firefox profile I actually can't find a way to log out of chat.stackexchange.com there.  :-)  However, if I create a new FF profile, login to stackoverflow.com again, and try to login to chat.stackexchange.com, the same problem occurs again - so it's reproducible.

Comment: @Jez - OK, I'll include the fallback information even if all tests pass. I'll also try to repro that scenario

Comment: @Marc can you not repro this?  I was hoping it'd be fixed by now but I still get the same problem logging in!

Comment: @Jez no, we cannot repro. This is.... odd. I will take another look. What is your setup? (OS, FF version?)

Comment: @Marc another point; that ghetto login doesn't exist for stackexchange.com (http://stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login).  Could it be added?

Comment: @Marc Windows 7, Firefox 4.0.1.

Comment: @Jez x86? x64? what?

Comment: x86 (ie. 32 bit)

Comment: @Marc x86 (does Twitter-style addressing really make a difference? :-)

Comment: @Jez - since you are replying *on my post*, I'll see your replies even without a @Marc - but in the general case, yes we have handling on @mentions

Comment: @Marc so any progress on this bug?

Comment: @Jez well, by progress do you include "get the 'data too old (whatever), so go to stackoverflow, log in again, go back to chat, click 'login', it all works fine" - i.e. still can't repro...?

Comment: @Marc well chat.stackoverflow.com is OK, it's chat.stackexchange.com I have the problem with.  I do go to stackexchange.com, log out and in again, then try chat.stackexchange.com.  The log in link is there to indicate I'm not logged in to chat, and when I click it I get the 'login data seems too old' message.  Voila.

Comment: @Jez - yes, I was testing against chat.SE, using my SO login

Comment: @Jez - it isn't trivial to repro, is what I am saying

Comment: @Marc well what can I say, it does happen for me.  :-)  Isn't there some way to debug it?  Would it be easier to go over it on MSN or Skype?

Answer (score 2):

Try https://chat.stackexchange.com/help for a diagnostic page.

I also recommend logging all the way out of a stackexchange site and then back in.