# (FF) can't login to skeptics.stackechange chat, but to the normal stackechange

Tags: support, chat, login, firefox

Browser Firefox 3.6.13

Login in Skeptics-chat fails, but not to Stackechange-chat. The diagnostic page at …

https://chat.stackexchange.com/help

… reveals something about my referrer:

```
IFRAMEs – ok
Referrer – failed

Your browser is not sending a recognized site in its HTTP referrer header.
We received "".
```

about:config shows:

```
network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer standard boolean true
```

[Ghetto-login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79641/why-cant-i-login-to-chat-stackexchange-com) works.

Logout/login doesn't work. I'm helpless.

Comment: It's a conspiracy.  Don't let them know you know.  Don't let them know you are letting them know you know.  Pretend not to know.  Inform others, in secret.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applicable Firefox about:config setting is

```
network.http.sendRefererHeader
```

and has to be set to `2` for chat.SE login (or global login in general) to work.

Comment: So is firefox wrong, calling that thing 'Referer' with single 'r'? Maybe the helpscreen could include a hint 'firefox -> about:config -> network.http.sendRefererHeader value 2'? At least it works now, after I changed it from 1 to 2. Do you have a brief sentence, what the values do?

Comment: @userunknown: a) the "Referer" thing is a long story -- simply put, a typo that made it into the standard (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)). b) If you (or some of your extensions) change your Refer(r)er settings, you have to accept that this may break the internet. We're not going to write up "What special settings to undo for it to work" how-tos for every browser and every setting you could possibly change. 3) AFAIK "2" always sends the refer(r)er, "1" sends it only when you clicked a link, "0" never sends it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your browser is misconfigured or has rogue extensions.

Try running Firefox in safe mode, that is, disable all extensions. Does that change the results?

Try using Google Chrome as well, to compare results.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but balpas hint is much faster testable, and it worked. :)