# Can't log in to chat

Tags: support, chat

I've tried several times to get chat working over the last couple months from several stackexchange sites, followed all of the instructions and it doesn't work.

The help pages reports that all the tests are ok. I've followed the instructions, logged out, logged back in, cleared cookies and cache, tried two different browsers and two different computers as well as the secondary option url. I've done all of this several times for travel, apple, stack overflow and stack exchange.

I'm using Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and also have tried Firefox 5.

Every time, when I get to the chat, it says that I need to be logged in to talk.

When trying the chat-login-workaround, I get page not found.

[image: Page not found]

Comment: You're not blocking cookies, are you?

Comment: No, I am not blocking cookies.

Comment: Hi: support request for more information - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just tested it, and it worked OK from here - a brief version of a successful login

```
GET  superuser.com          /users/chat-stackexchange-login
     (and click on the button)
POST chat.stackexchange.com /login/global-fallback
     (automatic redirect)
GET  chat.stackexchange.com /
```

At the moment, my biggest suspicion is that this relates to your openid (which is part of the handshake we use between the two systems). It is "a little unusual" as openids go. If you can let me know (privately if you need: marc.gravell@stackexchange.com) which openid provider that is, I will try to reproduce with something similar.

---

Update: confirmed; it looks like xri-based OpenIDs are a little less.... cooperative here. We have a repro, and are looking at it.

Comment: I was starting to suspect OpenID as that is the only thing I could think of that would be 'different' from a standard set up. I'll email you the details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try logging out of everything and clearing cookies and what all else (or simply use an icognito/private browsing session for the following).  Then go [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6944/g?tab=accounts) and hit <kbd>Copy Meta Stack Overflow login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts</kbd>.  Then try logging into chat.

If that doesn't work, try the chat-login-workaround: [Why can't I login to chat.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79641/why-cant-i-login-to-chat-stackexchange-com/79724#79724)

Comment: Tried both of those and the didn't work. When using the chat-login-workaround, I got Page Not Found. Given the different browsers and computers I have tried (and the fact that it seems to work for everyone else) I am wondering if it is related to my OpenID? I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is odd --

https://chat.stackexchange.com/help

does most of the troubleshooting that helps most folks. As Matthew indicated, try

- clean install of a browser you don't normally use (I recommend Chrome)
- log in and log out of a Stack Exchange site

Comment: Just installed Chrome and get the same thing -- it says that I need to login in order to talk.