# Can't log in; chat.stackexcange.com won't recognize my OpenID

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

I was logged into chat and Math.SE, but I needed to reset my connection. When I tried to log back in, I could connect to Math.SE, but chat.stackexchange.com would not recognize the same login. I use OpenID and Google to log in, and the email address for OpenID shows up under My Logins.

When I try to login I get this screen (I have removed my email address, but the email address that was removed shows up in `my logins`). I used this same login to access my non-chat accounts.

[image]

A few minutes after posting the last edit (with the image above), I was able to login to chat.  I didn't do anything other than try again.

Comment: What was the specific error message? Also, any screenshots?  Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101791/cant-log-in-to-chat